# concatenar los valores de una objeto pasandole un array con la clave de los valores

Tags: javascript

tengo un array1 de claves que me dan las claves de los valores que debo concatenar del array2 siendo el valor esperado, que devuelva

```
flatternArrayToString() --> ['aaabbb', 'dddeee', 'iiijjj']

let array1 =['keya','keyb']



let array2 = [{keya:'aaa', keyb: 'bbb', keyc: 'ccc' },{keya:'ddd', keyb: 'eee', keyc: 'hhh'},{keya:'iii', keyb: 'jjj', keyc: 'kkk'}]
```

Estoy tratando de hacer unb metodo que me concatene ambos valores, pero no lo consigo

```
  flatternArrayToString() {


  let array = [];
  for (let element of array2) {
    for (let key of array1) {
      array.push(element[key])
    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casi lo tenías, te faltaba concatenar en el último if y agregar esta concatenación al final

```js
let array1 =['keya','keyb'];
let array2 = [{keya:'aaa', keyb: 'bbb', keyc: 'ccc' },{keya:'ddd', keyb: 'eee', keyc: 'hhh'},{keya:'iii', keyb: 'jjj', keyc: 'kkk'}];

function flatternArrayToString(){
  let array = [];
  for (let element of array2) {
    let valor="";
    for (let key of array1) {
      valor += element[key];
    }
    array.push(valor)
    }
  return array;
}

console.log(flatternArrayToString());
```

Comment: estaba metiendo el let valor=""; en el lugar equivocado. Muchas gracias!